# How to create MySQL query for Crystal Report in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I already connected VB.Net, MySQL, and Crystal Report.

When I'm going to the print page form, it shows all data from my database, I wanted to get only specific ones, how can I do that?

Scenario of what's happening:

I'm developing a course scheduling system, and I want to print a schedule, all schedule(different courses, sections, departments) shows.

What I need is to select for example only Psychology-2A.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Invoke the hidden powers of the `where` clause

Comment: are you writing query in crystal reports or crystal reports is generating the query?